# Error usando stem en linea 43 (X must be same length as Y.)

Tags: matlab

Estoy realizando un codigo de convolucion en matlab
las cuales tiene la secuencia de entrada, respuesta al impulso y luego la convolucion.

```
n = -5:5;
x1 = stepseq(0,-5,5)-stepseq(10,-5,5);
x2 = (0.9).^n.*stepseq(0,-5,5);

y = conv(x1, x2);

figure
subplot(311);
stem(n,x1)
axis([-5 5 0 2]);
title('Secuencia de entrada');
xlabel('\bf n');
ylabel('\bf x(n)');

subplot(312);
stem(n, x2);
axis([-5 5 0 2]);
title('Respuesta el impulso');
xlabel('\bf n');
ylabel('\bf h(n)');

subplot(313);
stem(n, y);
axis([-5 5 0 2]);
title('Secuencia de Salida');
xlabel('\bf n');
ylabel('\bf y(n)');
```

pero me sale un error, no se si es por el intervalo de n o algo parecido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que defines el vector n=-5:5, lo cual crea un vector con elementos del -5 al 5 separados de 1 en 1, en cambio la convolución "combina" los vectores **x1** y **x2**, por lo que el tamaño de **y** no es el mismo de **n**. Puedes usar lo siguiente para graficar :

```
n2 = linspace(-5,5,length(y));
subplot(313);
stem(n2, y);
axis([-5 5 0 2]);
title('Secuencia de Salida');
xlabel('\bf n');
ylabel('\bf y(n)');
```

de esta manera creas un vector **n2** cuyos elementos vayan de -5 a 5 y su tamaño sea igual al de **y**